# Review Edit - Rejected

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Just need to confirm that those rejected reasons are correct. They say edit changes the original posts contents.

I don't think the meaning is changed in any way.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5860174

[image]

Comment: Robo-rejecters?  I have to say, it took me a minute to see where the code came from, so that's probably why these two rejected it.  Fortunately, your edit was approved.

Comment: It was not my code... as soon as i clicked edit the code was already there..I just formatted that :)

Comment: Should have said "the code."  I edited the prior comment.

Comment: Yea that might be the reason. But there was a reviewer before those  2 that actual approved.

Comment: The key is to sometimes describe to the reviewer what you are doing.  You say 'Added Code Bloack' - consider saying "Moved existing code into its own code block so that it would display correctly" - thus the reviewer knows what to look for.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will be doing same from now onwards.

Comment: The original code was also visible when switching to "markdown" mode in the review. But I mostly use "rendered output" myself. Certainly a mistake to reject the edit, but I don't blame them. This was so odd that many reviewers would have made the wrong call. A very good edit description definitely would have helped here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When viewing the question or when looking at the diff, the code disappeared (into the browser, I presume), which is why it showed up when you clicked "edit." But that also make it look like you added the code outright.

The reviewers didn't see where it came from, and assumed that you had added it to the question yourself.  Had they clicked "edit" on the question as you did, they would have seen that code.

Comment: That's why you check both tabs while reviewing...

Comment: Suggest you to quote MichaelT's comment for completeness `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I remember this one.

- I was viewing it in "rendered" mode and it looked like code came out of nowhere.
- I clicked the link to the original question to check further and did not see the code anywhere there, either.
- The comment "Added Code Bloack" to me sounded like the code *itself* was part of the edit, not that whitespace changes were made to make existing code appear.

It looked like the code was the editor's and had no connection to the OP, so I marked it *invalid edit*.

My mistake was not checking the markdown version. Then it would have been obvious what you did and I would have approved.

Sorry about that, I'm glad that other people made the right call.

Comment: This is exactly why a good edit comment is necessary.  "Added Code Block" is a bad description for a suggested edit.  Added from where?  Why?  Suggested editors need to make it simple for the reviewers, not force them to go hunting.